# mysqldump file creates an empty sql file

Tags: java, mysql

i apply comment 1 and 2 alternatively.But i didn't get myqldump file using java.mysqldump working in cmd. i think in cmd it ask password  after typing mysqldump comment. please help me fast.thanks in advance.

```
   String dumpCommand = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin\\mysqldump" + " -u " + user + " -p" + " " + database + " > " + path;
    **//command 1**
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    File test = new File(path);
    PrintStream ps;

    try {
    //    Process child = rt.exec("Cmd /c \"C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.0/bin/mysqldump\" -u root -p saxco > "+path);//command 2

        Process child = rt.exec(dumpCommand);
        ps = new PrintStream(test);
         InputStream in = child.getInputStream();
        int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
           ps.write(ch);
            System.out.write(ch);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password) you can specify the password in the command like this `[...] -pPASSWORD [...]`. Note that there must **not** be a space between the `-p` option flag and the actual password.

Keep in mind that specifying the password this way is a security risk!

Comment: it's my error please help **mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a password just don't use the -p option too.

String dumpCommand = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqldump" + " -u " + user + database + " > " + path;

or this if you have one (without the gaps)

String dumpCommand = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqldump" + " -u " + user + " -p" + password + " " + database + " > " + path;

Comment: mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database '>' when selecting the database.But it writing some data into .sql file.

Comment: Is the database variable empty?
Try to print dumpCommand before rt.exec()

Comment: The printed value should be like - 
"path-to-mysqldump[space]-u[space]user_name[space]database_name[space]>[space]some_name.sql"

Comment: I think the variables 'user' and 'database' are empty. Try to print them. as the error should have been like - 
Access denied for user 'user_name'@'localhost' to

Comment: no,i already initialized the variable user and database   **String database = "saxco";String user = "root";**                             printed value like this C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqldump -u rootsaxco > F:\1323.sql

Comment: try this just to debug your code instead. I think we will get a fair idea then:
String dumpCommand = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin\\mysqldump -u root saxco > out.sql";
If this works the problem lies in the variables.

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
String cmd="mysqldump -u "+USER+" -p"+PASSWORD+"  "+database+" --routines -r"+PATH;

                 Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                 Process exec;

                 exec = runtime.exec(cmd);

                 int processComplete = exec.waitFor();
         if(processComplete == 0){
         System.out.println("Backup taken successfully in "+PATH+" on "+new Date());
         } else {
         System.out.println("Could not take mysql backup  :ERROR:");
         }
```

Comment: it's my error please help **mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"**

Comment: your cmd String should be like--->                                                                                                                  "mysqldump -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASE_NAME -rD:\\dumpFile.sql";